# Apache Spark reduce action calling function more times than expected

Tags: java, apache-spark, rdd, fold

I have created an RDD like this:

```
JavaRDD<Integer> rdd = sc.parallelize(Arrays.asList(2, 3, 4));
```

And this Function2 class

```
public class FoldFunction implements Function2<Integer, Integer, Integer> {

    @Override
    public Integer call(Integer v1, Integer v2) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("v1 " + v1 + " v2 " + v2);
        return (v1.intValue() + 1);
    }
}
```

I then call the fold function like this:

```
Integer val2 = rdd.fold(0, new FoldFunction ());
```

The call function in the FoldFunction class is getting called four times, which is one more than I would have expected. The values for each call are:

```
v1 0 v2 2
v1 1 v2 3
v1 2 v2 4
v1 0 v2 3
```

I'm not sure why the call function is getting called four times, or why on the fourth call the parameters values are 0 and 3.

Can anyone shed some light on this?

I am using Java 8 and Spark Core 2.3.2
Thanks

Comment: Thanks for you're reply. I'll have to learn some scale to understand the answer.